# form validation for email website and phone number

Tags: javascript, html, validation

ami i doing something wrong here? I am trying to run a small piece of validation bny using javascript. Am I doing the regular expressions correctly?

```
var z=document.forms["myForm"]["website"].value;
if (z==null || z=="")
  {
  $('.five').show();
  return false;
  }
var validWebsite = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
if(!validWebsite.test(document.forms["myForm"]["website"].value))
{
  $('.five').html('Enter a Valid Website');
  return false;
}

var number = /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/
if(!number.test(document.forms["myForm"]["number"].value)){
    $('.six').show()
    return false;
}
```

html

```
*email: <br>
<input type="text" name="email"/><div class="four alertmessage" style="display:none;color:red;">Enter your Email</div><br>
website: <br>
<input type="text" name="website"/><div class="five alertmessage" style="display:none;color:red;">Enter your Website</div><br>
Contact phone number: <br>
<input type="text" name="number"/><div class="six alertmessage" style="display:none;color:red;">Enter your Number</div>

<input name="submit" class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: What's happening that you ask this question? Are you getting an error? Is it working? What troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: @john-- the website field is doing the validation but even after i am putting the cirrect website it is not moving to the next field.Lets say the website validation is not running properly

Comment: It would help if you could provide some context for how the javascript is triggered. Is this happening on the form's submit event? Try tweaking http://jsfiddle.net/fqbyK/ until you can recreate the problem.

Comment: @Divey- Thanks man. believe it or not there is no problem in tje snippet that provided but one after this. Some real minor syntax error. I took care of it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function validate()
{
    var z=document.forms["myForm"]["website"].value;
    if (z=="")
    {
        $('.five').show();
        return false;
    }

    var validWebsite = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
    if(!validWebsite.test(z)){
        $('.five').html('Enter a Valid Website');
        return false;
    }

    var n=document.forms["myForm"]["number"].value;
    var number = /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/;
    if(!number.test(n)){
    $('.six').show()
    return false;
    }

    return true;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" name="myForm"> 
*email: <br>
<input type="text" name="email"/><div class="four alertmessage" style="display:none;color:red;">Enter your Email</div><br>
website: <br>
<input type="text" name="website"/><div class="five alertmessage" style="display:none;color:red;">Enter your Website</div><br>
Contact phone number: <br>
<input type="text" name="number"/><div class="six alertmessage" style="display:none;color:red;">Enter your Number</div>

<input name="submit" class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```